# installing from Git errors python setupegg.py develop

Tags: ipython

I want to install the dev v. of ipython for Python3.2x

my environment

- /usr/bin/python3.2
- Python 3.2.3
- Linux Mint 13 64bit
- git version 1.7.9.5

I want to be able to pull the dev versions using:
git pull

as described in
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html

but `python3.2 setupegg.py` develop throws an error
as regular user

```
/usr/local/src/ipython $ python3.2 setupegg.py develop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setupegg.py", line 6, in <module>
    execfile('setup.py')
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

and as sudo

```
/usr/local/src/ipython $ sudo python3.2 setupegg.py develop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setupegg.py", line 6, in <module>
    execfile('setup.py')
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

What's the fix? Are the instructions accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPython cannot be installed as an egg with python 3+. Use `setup.py` to install.

Comment: to clarify here: IPython *always* uses setuptools on Python 3.  The `setupegg.py` is only there as a wrapper for setup.py to run with setuptools (which provides eggs, etc.). This is unconditional on Python 3, so `python3 setupegg.py` would be redundant.

Comment: @minrk Many thanks... but how to get Ipython dev 1.0 to use python3? I tried many permutations of python3 ipython.py (https://plus.google.com/u/0/116948076340592829238/posts/CXJsV9fvGj7) but Ipython dev 1.0 keeps using python 2.7.

Comment: You cannot run IPython from the source using python3 you **have to** install it or run 2to3 by hand. After installing you might need to launch `ipython3` instead of `ipython`

Comment: @Matt Wow. That really surprises me... I was under the impression the devs are building ipython using python3. Ok. Paradigm shift. I'll dig up the pages on installing from source. Thanks.

Comment: @pleabargain no, we do not develop with Python 3, that move will probably be made in a year or so (when 3.2 support is dropped).  Installing is one-line: `python3 setup.py install`, like pretty much all Python packages.